# Windows IOCP tree?

Tags: windows, io-completion-ports

What i want to do is the fallowing:
So i have 4 threads. and for each thread i create an IOCP. 
inside the thread function i wait on GetQueuedCompletionStatus(INIFINIT)
to get a job and then process it and then go wait again.

So if i want to submit a job to a specific thread i just PostQueuedCompletionStatus on its IOCP.

But what i want is to have like a master IOCP and inside the thread func. i GetQueuedCompletionStatus on the master IOCP , so when i post job on master IOCP random thread gets the job and process it, but i still want to send specific jobs for specific thread. How can i do that? thanks!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i did it myself, thanks.

this is the post_job function i wrote:

```
bool WINAPI world_server_process_job_async(job* j)
{
    if (j->type == J_W_RESOLVE)
    {
        for (uint32 i = 0; i < w_server.no_of_threads; i++)
            if (!PostQueuedCompletionStatus(w_server.world_worker_threads[i]->iocp, sizeof(job), NULL, (LPOVERLAPPED)j))
                w_server.resolve_drop_count++;
    }
    else
    {
        for (uint32 i = 0; i < w_server.no_of_threads; i++)
            if (w_server.world_worker_threads[i]->state == WORKER_INACTIVE)
                return PostQueuedCompletionStatus(w_server.world_worker_threads[i]->iocp, sizeof(job), NULL, (LPOVERLAPPED)j) ? true : false;

        bool result = PostQueuedCompletionStatus(w_server.world_worker_threads[w_server.last_to_do_work]->iocp, sizeof(job), NULL, (LPOVERLAPPED)j) ? true : false;
        if ((++w_server.last_to_do_work) >= w_server.no_of_threads) w_server.last_to_do_work = 0;
        return result;
    }
}
```